# Phantomjs error when evaluating

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I'm trying to login to my schools webpage using phantomjs but when I make it click on the login button using jquery, I get an error

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'form.timezoneOffset.value=now.getTimezoneOffset()')

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('webpageUrl', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if (status === "success") {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
      var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById('userid').value = "username";
        document.getElementById('pwd').value = "password";
        $('.form_button_submit').click();
      });
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      page.render("login.png");
      phantom.exit();
    }, 4000);
  }
});
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: (1) Which PhantomJS version do you use? (2) Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. (3) Btw, why are you including jQuery without using any of its functionality?

Comment: Hmm,. to use $('.form_button_submit').click(); I need to include it. If not it doesn't know what $ means. I ended up solving the problem by dispatching a mousevent myself on the element instead which seems to fix the problem. The same error comes up but the webpage redirects. Thanks for the answer through.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I haven't seen `$` for some reason. Also, this is not an answer, but rather a request for more information. Do you see some additional errors from the events?

Comment: That's the only error I see. From the source code of the webpage, it comes from var now=new Date();
    form.timezoneOffset.value=now.getTimezoneOffset(); -- But like I said, it seemed to only crash/stop responding when using jquery but not when vanilla javascript to click on the log in button.

Comment: You still haven't said which PhantomJS version you're using. If you're using 2.0.0, then you should try 1.9.8 and the other way around. There are three options what this might mean. Either `form`, `form.timezoneOffset` or `now` are undefined. I suspect something wasn't loaded, but PhantomJS 2.0.0 has a bug which doesn't show all errors.

Comment: 1.6.1 a pretty old jQuery version. You could try to use a newer version or simply stick to using `dispatchEvent()` in vanilla JS.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.2. I got it from the code.google.com but didn't realize it's not up to date. I'll try installing 1.9.8 and 2.0 later to see if it works with jQuery. But ya, I'm going to stick with vanilla since I don't really need jquery. I copied the jquery code from the gettign started guide and I didn't think of checking the version.